# Unit group of octonions over finite fields

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, octonions

One can define the algebra $A(K)$ of octonions over an arbitrary field $K$, see for example the command OctaveAlgebra in GAP: https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap62.html .
When $K$ is a finite field, this is a finite dimensional $K$-algebra and thus has finitely many elements. Let $A_q$ denote the octonions over a field with $q$ elemetns.

> Question 1: What is the number of units in $A_q$? Can one even describe the (possibly non-associative) group of units up to isomorphism?

For $q=2$ the order is 120 and for $q=3$ the order is 4320. In both cases it is indeed a group according to GAP.

Question 2 is motivated by Will Sawin's comment (I forgot the unit "group" might not be associative):

> Question 2: For which $q$ is the unit "group" of $A_q$ associative?

It would be interesting to see what the smallest $q$ is such that the unit "group" is not associative.

Comment: I guess it should  be a (Moufang) loop of units instead of a group, because it's not associative (except maybe in characteristic 2 it is). I don't know how easy those are to describe...

Comment: @WillSawin Thanks, I forgot about that. For $q=2$ and $q=3$ it is indeed a group according to GAP.

Comment: Units are exactly octonions with norm different from $0$, so you need to count the number of solutions of $\sum_{k=1}^8x_i^2\neq 0$, where $x_i\in \mathbb{F}_q$.

Comment: Just to add that GAP has a bug in dealing with the non-associativity here. This will be fixed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is all worked out in the article ["A class of simple Moufang loops"](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1956-007-03/S0002-9939-1956-0079596-1/) by L.J. Paige. The short answer is that the loop of units has size $q^3(q^4-1)(q-1)$, and is not associative for any $q$. The example given by Paige (lemma 3.5) is given in terms of [Zorn vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-octonion#Zorn%27s_vector-matrix_algebra) as
$$\left[\begin{pmatrix}
1 & (0,0,1)\\
(0,0,0) & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
1 & (1,0,0)\\
(0,0,0) & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}\right]\begin{pmatrix}
0 & (0,1,0)\\
(0,-1,0) & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & (1,1,1)\\
(-1,-1,1) & 2 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & (0,0,1)\\
(0,0,0) & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}\left[\begin{pmatrix}
1 & (1,0,0)\\
(0,0,0) & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
0 & (0,1,0)\\
(0,-1,0) & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}\right]=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & (1,1,1)\\
(-1,0,1) & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$
so these two products cannot be equal over any characteristic. For $q=2$ we obtain the smallest simple nonassociative Moufang loop, which has order 120.

The article actually shows that a certain subloop modulo its center is a simple Moufang loop. At the time before Paige's result, the only simple Moufang loops known where the simple groups. Liebeck later proved the converse: Every finite simple Moufang loop that is not a group corresponds to such a subloop of octonions over some $\mathbb F_q$. In particular we shouldn't expect a simple classification.

Comment: In fact Paige loops are not associative for $q\in \{2,3\}$ either (despite the claim in the OP), as stated in Theorem 4.1 of the linked article.

Comment: @pregunton Thanks for this comment. I obtained the units with the GAP command U:=units(A); and then it returns true when I check IsGroup(U); So maybe it is a GAP bug?

Comment: The article of Liebeck:  [The classification of finite simple Moufang loops](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0305004100067025) ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=886433)).

Comment: @Mare, it's a little hard to tell from [the documentation](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap56.html#X853C045B7BA6A580) whether `Units` is meant to handle a non-associative ring.  The [definition](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap56.html#X80FD843C8221DAC9) of a ring allows it, but then the documentation says that `Units` always returns a group, so it's not so clear.

Comment: I edited the answer to correctly reflect that Paige loops are always nonassociative. Some of the lemmas in the paper require being careful in the cases $q\in \{2,3\}$, but the part that shows nonassociativity works over all $q$.

Comment: @LSpice using the command StructureDescription(U) seems to calculate forever (even though U has only order 120 for q=2). So the developers also might forgot about the fact the units do not need to be associative.